# How can I set chrome selenium window size to match dimensions across different machines?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have automation running locally and jenkins (node) using headless with 1920x1080 width/height but dimensions return differently since they run on different machines.

My question is how can I set my chrome driver to have the same pixel ratio in both machines.

Mainly trying to set this consistent so when using doing image comparison for full page / element, they will pass locally and on jenkins.

Automation framework is using Protractor, so JavaScript.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you set up your Chrome webdriver? It should be possible to set the window size by something like `--window-size=1920,1080` as one of the webdriver's arguments.

Comment: I do have that in the config using 
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                "--window-size=1920,1080"
            ],
        },

but due to different machine's pixelDensity/pixelRatio, it throws images off by having different sizes

Comment: Are you using a protractor plugin to compare images? You may want to try to use one of these.
https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-image-comparison